# How to access onclick into many div

Tags: jquery

I need to react to the `onclick` event of an element that is found within two div

```
<div id="layout">
    <div id="home">
        <a id="Repair" href="javascript:void(0)"> Repair </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Repair is the one I want to access

Comment: `$('#layout').on('click',function(){
  var repairElement= $(this).find('#Repair");
});` It will be good if you elaborate on `click` of which `element` you want to access `#Repair`?

Comment: <a id="Repair" href="#" onclick="MyFunction();"> Repair </a> This will call MyFunction() function

Comment: `$("#Repair").click(function(){...code here...});`

Comment: Do you want the click on any of the container div to trigger the function with a target on the Repair one?

Answer (score 0):

First you should remove the href from the action link. If you are using jquery you can use either:

```
$("#layout").on('click', function(){
    var repair = $(this).find("a");
    ...
});
```

or directly :

```
$("#Repair").on('click', function(){
         ...
    });
```

there is also a third way with query that i like the most:

```
$(window).on( "click", "#Repair", function() {
...
});
```

or if you need plain javascript you can use:

```
var repairElement = document.getElementById('Repair');

repairElement.addEventListener('click', function() {
    .. some logic
}, false);
```